# Making a URL suffix to prefix

Tags: apache, http

I have a url [Like this: hostname.com] and I want to make hostname.com/blog to blog.hostname.com.  I am using Apache web server.  Let me know if I need to provide more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, it's been a while since I first made my SO account and this question. Anyway, I've learned a good amount since then, and now know that what I was trying to accomplish was to make a subdomain. The other two answers are correct in that it will setup a subdomain... if I had a domain pointing to it. I was using a NoIP domain for a tiny AWS free tier VPS, and the free NoIP stuff doesn't let you make a subdomain. I assumed that it would magically work if I told my VPS I wanted a subdomain. Whoops!

---

Backstory aside, to make a subdomain you need to use your domain host to add a new record pointing to your server, *and* configure your server to accept that new subdomain. Adding a subdomain depends on your provider, but now I use cloudflare, so adding an A / CNAME record following [this](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200168756-How-do-I-add-a-subdomain-) guide will work. Once you add the record, use the other two answers to make apache listen on that domain.

Thanks for the (almost) 5 years of answers to now, SO!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)? hostname\.com$
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)(/.*)?$ http://$1.hostname.com$2 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not just doing a redirect, and you're actually setting up a server on blog.hostname.com, then you would need to configure Apache to use another (virtual) host for each subdomain in extra/httpd-vhosts.conf. See http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/apache22_vhosts.php for a tonne of info on configuring Virtual Hosts.

Just a quick example from memory:

```
<VirtualHost blog.hostname.com:80>
    DocumentRoot /srv/www/blog
    ServerName blog.hostname.com
</VirtualHost>
```

This will mean that the virtual host on blog.hostname.com will display the same pages as hostname.com/blog. This is assuming your document root is /srv/www (ie a linux setup). If not, just insert the correct paths where necssary.